# Expand size of disk image after dd operation

Tags: disk-space, dd, disk-image

Background : I used the debian wheezy raspberry pi build, a generic kernel image with qemu to build a raspberry pi image.

I copied the resulting image to the SD card with dd. That SD card is a 16 gb card.

After the dd operation the result on the SD card only has about 5 gb of space. ( df -h)

My question: what did I do wrong to limit the size of the image? Why doesn't the result on the SD card have the full 16 gb of disk space available?

Second question : do I have to rebuild the image from scratch or can I expand it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the input file as the image it just copied the image. Had you set the input file as a device with 16 GB it would have completed the 16 GB of your SD card.